# How to register custom CollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I have been so far using UITableViews successfully, but I can't get UICollectionView working.

```
@interface NewsCollectionViewDataSource : NSObject <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TNCollectionViewCell *newscell = nil;
    newscell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:newsCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!newscell) {
        [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"TNCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    newscell.newsLabel.text = [[self newsForIndexPath:indexPath] headLine];
    return newscell;
}
```

Everytime I get everytime to the line:

```
newscell.newsLabel.text = [[self newsForIndexPath:indexPath] headLine];
```

newscell is nil.

Am I registering it wrong?

Comment: Where's the register call?

Comment: I was under the impression that the line starting with `[[NSBundle bundleForClass` would take care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere before retrieving cells for `collectionView` (i.e. in `viewDidLoad`) call the following method of `UICollectionView`

```
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

In your case it would be something like that:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TNCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] 
      forCellWithReuseIdentifier:newsCellReuseIdentifier];
```

and then there will be no need for the following code:

```
if (!newscell) {
    [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"TNCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am quite confused now. I am following the book 'Test driven development' by Graham Lee and he uses only the latter line. See on his github: https://github.com/iamleeg/BrowseOverflow/blob/edf96c7a229c6ba38e0236ddc15041196b789841/BrowseOverflow/QuestionListTableDataSource.m#L34  How is that possible?

Comment: @Houman as I can understood, this code last time was edited on 22 Nov 2011 so it is too old to be used as a modern guide

Comment: Yes thank you. It works.  That book is no longer very useful anymore. Have to cherry pick some strategies and rethink it.